# Is there a non-multiplication operator on $L^2([0,1])$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I just learned about multiplication operator on $L^2[0,1]$. These are defined as an operator of the form $M_f(h(t))=f(t)h(t)$ for all $h\in L^2[0,1]$ and for some $f\in L^{\infty}([0,1])$. Do these operators exhaust all operators on $L^2[0,1]$? That is, is there a non-multiplication operator on $L^2[0,1]$?

Comment: The map that sends a function to it's integral times the identity function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The absolute majority of the bounded operators on $L^2[0,1]$ are **not** multiplication operators.

Let's see:

- $M_f$ is normal for all $f$. There are many many non-normal operators in $B(L^2[0,1])$.
- $M_f$ is never compact.

Those two give you scores of examples of operators that are not multiplication operators. Even more,

- the algebra $A$ of multiplication operators is not dense in $B(L^2[0,1])$ in any of the usual topologies (norm, sot, wot, etc.). This is easily seen from the fact that $A$ is maximal abelian.

Some concrete examples of non-normal operators: let $H$ be any Hilbert space. Fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\} _{n\in\mathbb N}$.

- Let $E_{12}$ be the linear operator induced by $E_{12}e_1=e_2$, $E_{12}e_n=0$ for $n\geq2$. Then $E_{12}^*=E_{21}$ and $E_{12}^*E_{12}=E_{22}$, $E_{12}E_{12}^*=E_{11}$.
- Similarly one can define $E_{kj} $ for $k\ne j$.
- The *unilateral shift* is the linear operator $S$ induced by $Se_n=e_{n+1}$. It satisfies $S^*S=I$, $SS^*=I-E_{11}$.

Comment: Indeed, I also observed they're normal and I find it unlikely that all operators on $L^2[0,1]$ are normal. However, I couldn't construct a non-normal operator because I always fall back to multiplication operators (hence the question).

Answer (score 0):

If you want some example of non multiplicative operator, you have the differential operators, like
$$
(-\Delta)^{-s} f = \frac{C}{|x|^{1-s}} * f
$$
that are also continuous operators on $L^2([0,1])$ for any $s\in(0,1)$, and more generally, the operator of convolution by a nice function.These can be thought of as multiplication operator after taking the Fourier transform.

In general, one can write an operator as a pseudodifferential operator, so general operators can be thought of as operators of the form $f(x,\nabla)$.

Comment: Based on my limited understanding, usually differential operators are not defined on the entire Hilbert space. So I'm not sure your example works for my question.

Comment: If it is a differential operator of positive order, then it is indeed unbounded on $L^2$, which is why I am taking the example of a differential operator of negative order